# REQUEST_URI unexpectedly contains FQDN

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

On my main web server, the $_SERVER variable REQUEST_URI always contains something like "/filename.php" however on my development server (PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.3, Apache 2.2.17) the same variable contains "http://www.example.com/filename.php" (e.g. includes the fully qualified domain name not just the path).

This is causing problems for several CMS packages I work with (e.g. Wordpress and Joomla) which seem to rely on the contents of REQUEST_URI.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I need to change on the development server to make REQUEST_URI behave as expected?

Comment: What server is it and what version?

Comment: Development server details: PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.3, Apache 2.2.17

Comment: Main server: PHP 5.2.17, Apache 2.2.21

Comment: Question resolved (I can't answer by own question for another 7 hours), I was using FoxyProxy to redirect certain URL's to localhost and it was this redirection causing the problem not a server setup issue. Editing /etc/hosts instead of using the proxy method solves the problem.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. You can choose either to delete the question (if you think it's unlikely to have value to future readers) or self-answer it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using proxy & HTTP 1.1 leads to full URL in REQUEST_URI variable in Apache. Web applications have to test REQUEST_URI  before trying to concatinate it with host (this bug exists in Wordpress CMS for example).

Comment: December 2019 and still there, noone uses it or what? :o