# Redirecting based on condition

Tags: php

I do have the following code:

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'http://example.com/knowthecode')
{
    header("Location: http://example.org/knowthecode"); exit;
}
```

This is NOT working as expected. Can you help ?

Comment: Output the content of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and see whats inside.

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Comment: You are redirecting from example.com to example.org?  A better approach to handling two domains is to use 301 redirects and a .htaccess file to redirect from one domain to another.  Google and search engines like that method better.

Comment: It does not *typically* contain the full URL. That's actually a server setup thing; in particular [for proxy setups `REQUEST_URI` can contain the complete URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040461/request-uri-unexpectedly-contains-fqdn). (Still, not usually for PHP scripts, nor per the CGI spec.)

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` does not hold the entire URL (as suggested in the comments).

While there are other elements in [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) that may ultimately hold what you need, you'd be better off using a function like [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and then comparing the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

The `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` does not include the host of the site - for page like http://www.mysite.com/page.php?key=value the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` will be `/page.php?key=value"

try looking at the `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` in order to search on the host as well.

and a good approach would be to add:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

this will help you understand what server vars are and what do they mean

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

REQUEST_URI is the request sent to your server(domain)

for example in http://www.domain.com/index.php the REQUEST_URI is /index.php

What you could do is this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php')
{
    header("Location: http://www.google.com"); 
    exit;

}
```

Comment: I do not have the page names like "knowthecode.php" but user may hit the browser by using teh url - 'http://example.com/knowthecode'. Can you explain to me how to know this on server side ?